# Sockets io - managing multiple rooms?

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

Having trouble managing multiple rooms with node.js and socket.io

```
socket.on('join_room', function (data) {
   socket.join(data);
});

 socket.on('send_msg', function (data) {
   io.sockets.in(theroom).emit('message', data);
});
```

If I set the room in a variable (i.e `theroom`) then naturally that gets over written with the latest room, how can I have multiple rooms?

Comment: Post the code, where you declare and set theroom

Comment: here is a tutorial I wrote about multi room chat: http://udidu.blogspot.co.il/2012/11/chat-evolution-nodejs-and-socketio.html

Comment: Thanks guys, im following this now:  http://psitsmike.com/2011/10/node-js-and-socket-io-multiroom-chat-tutorial/
i just dont understand how rooms are managed, in the linked, they are stored in socket.room but how is this managed,  how does it remember which room each user belongs to, after rooms are changed etc

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by writing a function that sends to rooms:

```
listen: (server, callback) =>
  @server = server
  @logger.debug 'SDL: starting up socket'
  # @socketTool is object returned by socket io require 
  @listener = @socketTool.listen(server, log: true, 'log level': @logLevel )

emitToRoom: (room, type, data, callback) =>
  @logger.debug "all rooms: #{@utilLib.inspect @listener.sockets.manager.rooms}"
  @listener.sockets.in(room).emit(type, data)
  callback() if callback?
```

I think the thing that you're missing is that the individual socket doesn't understand other rooms, you need to handle that at the listener level.